# ASP.NET application not sending emails with SendGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

I have recently set up my project with SendGrid and did the walkthrough with the integration set up. However when I try to verify my email or send an email from my application to complete the set up, it doesn't seem to be working. I was wondering if there was anything I have missed, or if there is a better way to set up email verification in ASP.NET MVC.

Here is my code for it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using A2HIT339WebApp.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using SendGrid;

namespace A2HIT339WebApp
{
    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public async Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your SMS service here to send a text message.
            await configSendGridasync(message);
        }

        private async Task configSendGridasync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("A2HIT339");
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var from = new EmailAddress("maya.jenkins98@outlook.com", "Example User");
            var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
            var to = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
            var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
            var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
            var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
    }

    public class SmsService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your SMS service here to send a text message.
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    // Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            // Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();

            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;

            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }

            return manager;
        }
    }

    // Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
        }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, here is my code isn't really a good question is it? What did you expect to happen, do you see errors, what did you try, what did you expect, have you tried to debug yourself?

Comment: When the code is added in the program it is meant to be able to send an email to SendGrid to verify it is set up properly. Pretty much I followed all the steps and added it into the code but for some reason the email isn't sending to SendGrid to confirm it is working so I was wondering if I messed up my code somewhere or there is other stuff I need to add. Idk if that makes sense.

Comment: Well since you never call your SendAsync I would assume you can't see if it's working or not. Not to be harsh, but do you have any idea what you're doing?

Comment: `configSendGridasync` looks fine. Can you extract your code into a console application to remove all the moving parts around the SendGrid code? This will make it easier to track down the issue. Is `maya.jenkins98@outlook.com` a verified sender in SendGrid?  You should be able to see your emails in your email activity feed and if they were delivered or not, as described here: https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/analytics-and-reporting/email-activity-feed